# Re-attaching jQuery function after dynamically loading html

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have been searching and experimenting for a few hours now, and I think the solution lies in the `.on()` function in jQuery.  But I can't seem to figure out the correct implementation.

I have a tabbed menu and I would like to add content to one of the tabs as a dropdown, the content should get loaded at `document.ready`:

```
<div id="container" class="layout" style="border: 1px solid">
   <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a id="go_archives" href="#">Archives</a> </li>
    <li><a id="go_answers" href="#">Puzzle Answers</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

Here is the associated CSS:

```
/* menu tab styling */

ul.tabs {
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px 2px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00AEDB;
}

ul.tabs li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

ul.tabs a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 7px 4px 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

ul.tabs a:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FFF;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

/* dropdown styling */

ul.dropdown {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 100%;
  left:0;
}

ul.dropdown ui.dropdown {
  top: 0;
  left: 95%;
}

ul.dropdown li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
}

ul.dropdown li a {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

and the JS

```
$('.dropdown').parent().mouseenter(function () {
    $('.dropdown', this).slideToggle('fast');
  });

$('.dropdown').parent().mouseleave(function () {
    $('.dropdown', this).slideUp('fast');
  });
```

All of this works fine to slide out the UL under the `go_answers` LI.

In Firebug I run the following:

```
$.get("shite.html", function(result){
    $("#go_archives").parent().append(result);
  });
```

which loads shite.html

```
<ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">five</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">six</a></li>
</ul>
```

and it updates the DOM (I think that's the correct term) however when I mouse over the Archives link it doesn't slide out.

What am I missing to make it slide out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you dynamically reload the DOM elements like that you need to reattach the events. You should put your mouseenter and mouseleave commands in a function and call that function on document ready and within your get.

I set up a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WHgNP/) to demonstrate how you could go about setting this up. The results that you have presented as being the return from an ajax call I just stored in a hidden div and when you click the test button it adds the div contents to your list item. Once the new DOM elements are in place we re-run your jquery to have the selector pick up the new elements and after manipulating the css class so you get the expected presentation your drop down works.

The overall point is to keep in mind that the events that you're assigning to the results from your Jquery selector are only added to those elements that match the selector at the time that it runs. If you insert new elements into your DOM that would have matched the selector it doesn't mean that your new elements will also pick up the attached behavior.

Comment: That's an interesting approach.  I will experiment with it.  thanks

Comment: @user1681222 Hopefully the fiddle will be useful for you

Comment: bang on.  and it seems far more responsive than the solution I had been playing with.

Answer (score 2):

You clould implement .on() method that way :

```
$("#container").on({
    mouseenter: function (event) {    
       $('.dropdown', this).slideToggle('fast');
    },            
    mouseleave: function (event) {
       $('.dropdown', this).slideUp('fast');   
    },
    mousedown: function (event) {
       //Do stuff
    }
    },
    ".dropdown"
);
```

Comment: Excellent example.  I've always used `.on` for single events, didn't know you could setup multiple types of events in the call.

Comment: Complete function signature : .on( events-map [, selector] [, data] )

Comment: not sure exactly if I understood.  I copied the above snippet and pasted it into my js file (i left out the mousedown event) I commented out my original mouse events.  When I reload the page the dropdown under go_answers no longer works.  and when I load the shite.html page the drop down doesn't work there either.  Firebug doesn't report any errors on reload either

Answer (score 0):

I wasfacing the same problem

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $(".mytable").on('click', '.toggle', function () {
    alert("toggle Clicked");
    });
});
```

Html Before ajax

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links" id="tab-links">

    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="tab-content">

    </div>
</div>
```

Html after ajax

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links" id="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>        
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active" >
            <table id="mytable1" class="mytable">
                <tr data-depth="0" class="expand level0">
                    <td>
                    <span class="toggle expand">+</span>
                    Everything Else [<a class="link">99</a>]
                    </td>   
                    <td> 1$</td>    
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It was not working then i change it to

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.mytable .toggle', function () {
    alert("toggle Clicked");
    });
});
```

It was working fine now.